# CSS - Align image in a wordpress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need to align the image 'Special offers' on the site http://sherridon.bluefrogclients.com/.

I need to move it up a bit.

Let me know what exactly to change.

Below is the code from css file:

```
#call_to_action {
    background: #e6e6e6 url("images/outset_breadcrumbs.gif") repeat-x scroll center bottom;
    min-height: 170px;
}

body.inset #call_to_action {
    background-image: url("images/inset_breadcrumbs.gif");
}
#call_to_action #blurb {
    padding: 15px 230px 20px 0;
}
#call_to_action_button {
    background: url("images/started.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 300px;
}
#call_to_action_button a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Regards, 
Shyam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@corroded's answer looks correct also (gave +1), but mine makes better use of your existing code:

- Your image is exactly `89px` high.
- You already have a `top` attribute which you can make use of, you don't need `margin-top`.

  ```
  #call_to_action_button {
      height: 89px;
      top: -29px
  }
  ```

  (in *blue.css*)

Answer (score 2):

In blue.css:

```
#call_to_action_button {
  margin-top: -30px;
  height: 90px;
}
```

Increase it as you much as you like(or decrease)

I noticed your image wasn't showing well. so I added the height and compensated with the margin top